# Is it okay to write "Please give this post few more upvotes so that I earn a silver badge"?

Tags: discussion

I am explaining this question w.r.t myself. These are four of my questions:

1. [How do aircraft land on snow?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/16100/how-do-aircraft-land-on-snow)(22 upvotes)
2. [Are nuclear bombers themselves damaged after dropping bombs?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15933/are-nuclear-bombers-themselves-damaged-after-dropping-bombs)(22 upvotes)
3. [Why are the call signs of some airlines completely different than their name?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15847/why-are-the-call-signs-of-some-airlines-completely-different-than-their-name)(21 upvotes)
4. [Why are Low Cost Carriers ordering several hundred aircraft?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15545/why-are-low-cost-carriers-ordering-several-hundred-aircraft)(21 upvotes).

Would it be okay to literally ask users to give me a few more upvotes, so that I earn the    [Good Question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/21/good-question?userid=8482) badge?

Comment: begging for upvotes is frowned upon and mass upvotes can and will be reverted when detected

Comment: upvotes are not 'likes', they don't mean we like the post author or post, it means we found the post *useful*

Comment: And it should be noted, @casey's logic should be applied to this question as well.  It's a very useful question, I'm not sure why anyone is down voting it.

Comment: You answered your own question - "so that I **earn** the Good Question badge"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was in a similar position once when several of my posts were stuck at 24 votes. Apparently, it does sound convincing to ask for an up vote, so that you can earn a specific badge. But before you do that, please remember the following:

- Some people will be *offended* if you ask for an up vote. Though SE encourages people to up vote, many people don't do it because it costs them a lot of money.<sup>1</sup>
- When you are asking for up votes here, the people who will read your request would probably have already up voted your answer. You can see [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) that a group of people (although small) votes a lot. In addition, the [electorate](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate) badge (which is geared towards up voting questions) has been awarded many times.
- If you just concentrate on asking good questions and providing good answers, you will keep on getting up votes, even months after those posts. The more content you add, the more likely it will be noticed by different people.
- And finally, the most important point is what I wrote at the end of [this post](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1638/65), which you already know.

---

<sup>1</sup>: This is just a comical reference.

Comment: How does it cost money to vote?

Comment: I too am puzzling on that one, clarification? (If in duplication?)

Comment: @Lnafziger Can't a man make a joke.

Comment: @JayCarr Clarification added.

Comment: lol, I may downvote my own answer on the strength of that footnote...

Answer (score 9):

Gonna have to say no on this one.  The fact of the matter is that the votes are supposed to help us figure out how good the question or answer actually is, and having the votes inflated (or deflated) for any reason would skewer an already imperfect system so...  Yeah, I don't think you should be doing that.

Comment: I think, SE is one of the most perfect systems..!!

Comment: @anshabhi Personally I think SE has flaws coming out of it's ears (meaning: a lot).  But it's still quite useful.

Comment: It is very useful but far from perfect.

Answer (score 1):

There are some other ways that you can encourage traffic to your content that shouldn't appear as begging and will help improve the quality of the site:

1. Post an answer on a related question, referencing your original post. The answer should add new information and be able to stand on its own, only linking the other post for additional information.
2. Post a new question, referencing your original post. The question should be new and unique and be helpful to others, only referencing the original post by relation or for additional information.

Both of these options will get you additional votes on the new posts as well as (hopefully) bringing new viewers and votes to the older ones, if you make sure that these new posts are helpful and of good quality.

As [Farhan mentioned](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1677/1696), other users may happen to do these things for you on their own in the future, so having more good quality posts will help.

As a last resort, there is also a third option, which adds less quality but also doesn't provide for added reputation:

3. Leave a comment on a related question/answer, which will add helpful information. Since you can't include as much in a comment, this is harder to create a useful context and so should be used with care to avoid giving the impression of begging for votes. Comments also don't get as much visibility and are [more at risk of deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130975/257476).

Of course in all of these cases, it will be better if you link to posts by other users as well and not always your own. I like to think that if you link to posts by other users, others are more likely to do the same for your own.